# FFmpeg: stream audio playlist, normalize loudness and generate spectrogram and waveform

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, waveform, spectrogram

I would like to use FFmpeg to stream a playlist containing multiple audio files (mainly FLAC and MP3). During playback, I would like FFmpeg to normalize the loudness of the audio signal and generate a spectrogram and waveform of the audio signal separately. The spectrogram and waveform should serve as a audio stream monitor. The final audio stream, spectrogram and waveform outputs will be sent to a browser, which plays the audio stream and continuously renders the spectrogram and waveform "images". I would also like to be able to remove and add audio files from the playlist during playback.

As a first step, I would like to use the `ffmpeg` command to achieve the desired result, before I'll try to write code which does the same programmatically.

(sidenote: I've discovered [`libgroove`](https://github.com/andrewrk/libgroove) which basically does what I want, but I would like to understand the FFmpeg internals and write my own piece of software. The target language is Go and using either the [`goav`](https://github.com/giorgisio/goav) or [`go-libav`](https://github.com/imkira/go-libav) libraries might do the job. However, I might end up writing the code in C, then creating Go language bindings from C, instead of relying on one of the named libraries.)

Here's a little overview:

```
playlist (input) --> loudnorm --> split --> spectrogram --> separate output
                                    |
                                  split ---> waveform ----> separate output
                                    |
                                    +------> encode ------> audio stream output
```

For the loudness normalization, I intend to use the `loudnorm` filter, which implements the EBU R128 algorithm.

For the spectrogram, I intend to use the `showspectrum` or `showspectrumpic` filter. Since I want the spectrogram to be "steamable", I'm not really sure how to do this. Maybe there's a way to output segments step-by-step? Or maybe there's a way to output some sort of representation (JSON or any other format) step-by-step?

For the waveform, I intend to use the `showwaves` or `showwavespic` filter. The same as for the spectrogram applies here, since the output should be "streamable".

I'm having a little trouble to achieve what I want using the `ffmpeg` command. Here's what I have so far:

```sh
ffmpeg \
    -re -i input.flac \
    -filter_complex "
      [0:a] loudnorm [ln]; \
      [ln] asplit [a][b]; \
      [a] showspectrumpic=size=640x518:mode=combined [ss]; \
      [b] showwavespic=size=1280x202 [sw]
    " \
    -map '[ln]' -map '[ss]' -map '[sw]' \
    -f tee \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 \
    "
      [aselect='ln'] rtp://127.0.0.1:1234 | \
      [aselect='ss'] ss.png | \
      [aselect='sw'] sw.png
    "
```

Currently, I get the following error:

```
Output with label 'ln' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.
```

Also, I'm not sure whether `aselect` is the correct functionality to use. Any Hints?

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. I don't think `aselect` is correct; it selects *frames* to send to the output, rather than streams. Try this instead:

```
ffmpeg \
    -re -i input.flac \
    -filter_complex "
      [0:a] loudnorm , asplit=3 [a][b][ln];
      [a] showspectrumpic=size=640x518:mode=combined [ss];
      [b] showwavespic=size=1280x202 [sw]
    " \
    -map '[ln]' -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f rtp 'rtp://127.0.0.1:1234' \
    -map '[ss]' ss.png \
    -map '[sw]' sw.png
```

Notice that the `loudnorm` and `asplit` filters are combined into a *filterchain*. From the documentation:

> A filterchain consists of a sequence of connected filters, each one connected to the previous one in the sequence. A filterchain is represented by a list of ","-separated filter descriptions. A filtergraph consists of a sequence of filterchains. A sequence of filterchains is represented by a list of ";"-separated filterchain descriptions.
> [[1]](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1)

Each `-map` option selects a stream and sends it to the next output file or stream. So in this case the `[ln]` stream is sent to the `rtp` stream, `[ss]` is sent to `ss.png`, and so on.